# Is the verb plural or singular where the subject is unclear?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, subjects

I'm editing this sentence:

> Keep in mind that the judge, and probably a law clerk too, [have/has] read your ?>papers and submissions and [are/is] familiar with the case."

The question is whether the 'have' and 'are' should be singular referring to the judge, or plural because there's reference to the clerk as well. To me, it reads better in the singular since the clerk is added as an aside. Which is correct in this situation?

Comment: I'm in the "have" and "are" camp, as "and" includes the law clerk (even if you wrote "perhaps" instead of "probably"). I would also use "as well" instead of "too." If you lean strongly towards using the singular for stylistic purposes or for emphasis, just eliminate reference to the law clerk.

Comment: Though this is a good question, I have to vote to close as primarily opinion-based, unless you can provide some specific meaning of 'correct'.

Comment: There is a tension between 'coordinated subjects take a plural verb-form unless treated as notionally singular' and 'parentheticals don't cause adjustment for agreement'. Doubtless opinions will differ over how much of a parenthetical 'and probably a law clerk too' is, but I've never been happy with 'because it is/isn't' answers here.

Comment: I posted it because I figured there was a correct answer due to the parenthetical nature of the law clerk. I didn't know if there was some rule to rely on.